# Using "proof by contradiction" to show that no integer can be both odd and even

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having some trouble with the following homework problem:

> Use "proof by contradiction" to explain why no integer can be both odd and even.

So, far I think that I need to start with a counterexample which would be any integer $2k+1$ for odd and $2n$ for even.  So my question is, what does it mean when it says "and"?

Comment: If $2k + 1 = 2n$ it seems logical that $2(k-n) = 1$, so that $k - n = \frac{1}{2}$ is an integer. Does this seem like a problem to you?

Comment: I don't understand where you got the 2(k-n) = 1 part???

Comment: Let's say your "even and odd" integer is $t$. Since $t$ is odd, $t = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$, Since $t$ is even, $t = 2n$ for some integer $n$. But $t = t$, so $2k + 1 = 2n$. And...oops, I made a mistake, it should be: $2(n-k) = 1$.

Comment: Anyway, $2k ++ 1 = 2n$ means $1 = 2k + 1 - 2k = 2n - 2k = 2(n-k)$. Sorry for the mix-up.

Comment: Great.  I was just making it too hard.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is odd then $x=2k+1 $ , $k\in \mathbb {Z}$ . For hip. $x$ is also even, then $2$ divide $x$, but $2$ divide $2k$
, therefore $2$ divide $1$. Absurd!